# How to change the origin header when using webpack dev server

Tags: webpack-dev-server

My server is actively refusing the the request not from "localhost" and it's own IP address.  This makes it hard, for example, I'm starting up a dev server on my desktop A, and I want to use it from desktop B.

Is there any way to change the origin header?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. Why do you want to change the origin header? Try starting the server with the `--host x.x.x.x` flag (change x.x.x.x to your ip address, or even `0.0.0.0`).

There's some other stuff you can try in [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/345) as well.